# Rational / Irrational Limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 x%2&\text{if}\, \\
 &\text{if}\, \text{x is irrational}\\
      2x+1 &\text{x is rational}
\end{cases}
$

Does the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$ exist ?

I wasn't too sure but checked both sides of the limit and concluded that they are both equal to $0$. As they are equal the limit must exist.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0, x\in\mathbb{Q}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0,x\in\mathbb{Q}}2x+1=1$, while $\lim_{x\to 0, x\not\in\mathbb{Q}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0,x\not\in\mathbb{Q}}x=0$. "Sides" is not the partition of the reals that is useful in this problem, but rationals and irrationals.

Comment: You missed that you approach $1$ , if $x$ approaches $0$ with a rational sequence.

Comment: @owl Okay so the limit doesn't exist ? Also, it isn't continuous at $x=0$, right ?

Comment: Yes, if the limit doesn't exist, then it is not continuous.

Comment: In fact, $f$ is continuous only at $x=-1$ (the only place where $x=2x+1$)